# Get XML's info using arrayWithContentsOfFile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I'm trying to get XML's info **by using NSFileManager and fill content of array by arrayWithContentsOfFile method**.
The problem is when I print this array, it will appears as **'null'**. I'm thinking about an encoding problem, but not sure...?

**My code :**

```
NSString *evalPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/eval_list.xml", [UIAppDelegate documentsPath]];
NSArray *evalList = [[NSArray alloc] init];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:evalPath]) {
     evalList = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:evalPath];
     NSLog(@"Content of Array : %@", evalList);
     if (evalList && ([evalList count]))
        evalList = [UIAppDelegate postProcessEvalList:evalList];
}
```

**But :**

```
NSLog(@"Content of Array : %@", evalList);
```

**Return 'null'**. Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: You cant convert xml directly to array like that. Rather you will have to parse the xml by yourself. Use stringWithContentsOfFile: to fetch the content into string and then convert it to xml using NSXMLParser and convert it to array by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how do you convert string into xml by using NSXMLParser ?

Comment: See this link for details http://iosbala.blogspot.fi/2013/04/how-to-using-nsxmlparser-in-iphone-sdk.html

Comment: @insane-36 Please post an answer to this question so that madr4s can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant convert xml directly to array like that. Rather you will have to parse the xml by yourself. Use stringWithContentsOfFile: to fetch the content into string and then convert it to xml using NSXMLParser and convert it to array by yourself.

See this link for details http://iosbala.blogspot.fi/2013/04/how-to-using-nsxmlparser-in-iphone-sdk.html on how to parse xml.